# When flagging a question, I get a 404 error

Tags: bug, status-completed, flag-dialog

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/637318/how-to-open-multiple-tabbed-files-in-vim-each-at-a-specified-line/) is the question I'm attempting to flag as a duplicate.

When I click on duplicate, a red popup comes up simply stating "404" (although I assume it's meant to respond with a "Done" or "Error" type of message):

[image: Screenshot of said bug]

Chrome Dev Tools console shows:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://superuser.com/flags/questions/637322/close/popup?_=1377622359605`

Comment: What post were you trying to link as a duplicate?

Comment: I did link it in the question. Here it is: http://superuser.com/questions/637318/how-to-open-multiple-tabbed-files-in-vim-each-at-a-specified-line/

Comment: I meant which post where you trying to say that was a duplicate of. (Because the link in your answer is on stackoverflow and you can't close as duplicates across sites)

Comment: FDinoff - I wasn't aware duplicates couldn't be across sites. Thanks for that! Still, the bug remains (as I hadn't entered a duplicate URL as of yet).

@hjpotter92 - That may (quite ironically) be the case. I'm using Chrome 28.0.1500.95m (someone else reported the problem with the same version). However could someone who knows better verify if this URL would be the correct one generated? If so, I'm sure we could trace the cause of the issue.